# Best alternative approach to define a Partial Module in Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, organization, partial-classes, convention

### SCENARIO

---

Imagine that you, the programmer, is developing an API with a module file lets say **BitmapExtensions.vb** which is full of extension methods, each extension method has for example 20 overloads, and this causes the source code to increase miles of lines of code,

then, to be productive in our programming environment sure you would like to sepparate each method into different files (a kind of partial modules with the same module name, like we do with partial classes), however, a partial Module cannot be defined and a Class does not support extension methods in Vb.Net,

this totally breaks the user experiencie and programmer productivity because all are disadvantages, when searching an specific overload or to add more, always requiring the usage of the vertical scrollbar on the Visual Studio code editor to scroll thousands and thousands of lines, or using the search-box to find a method name a lot of times because all the methods with all their overloads are messed in the same file... also, its just very ugly.

### QUESTION

---

Just... if possible, what the hell the programmer could do to organize the source code architecture in these circunstances?.

I really don't want to keep a module file which consists in 3.000 lines of code, I want 500 lines of code in 1 file (which means 1 method with all their overloads) preserving the same name(space), and so on with the other members into sepparated files.

Is this possibly to do in some way?.

PS: Of course translating extension methods to common methods to gain the beneffits of defining partial classes is not an option.

Comment: I dont get it.  If I put one extension method in `Ext1` and an overload in `Ext2` they still show up in intellisense as overloads.  Why do you care what the module name is?  The only place that seems to be differentiated is in the Object Browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT of August 3rd, 2016**

Partial Modules and Interface are available since VB .Net 14.0.

**Original Answer**

Well, known the fact of Type Promotion with Modules (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz7s1h1x.aspx), you create one Namespace, then you split it into module files. If all the methods are unique in the namespace, you just have to import the namespace, they will be accessible without having to name the modules...

I guess that is why modules cannot be partial, because the module name can be omitted if the method is unique.

File test1.vb

```
Namespace Test
   Module Test1
     Function Hello() as String
       ...
     End Function
   End Module
End Namespace
```

File test2.vb

```
Namespace Test
   Module Test2
     Function Hi() as String
       ...
     End Function
   End Module
End Namespace
```

Other File

```
Imports Test
Public Function MyFunc() as String
  Return Test.Hi()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that VB.Net Partial Modules are supported in VS 2015 - [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350(v=vs.140).aspx). Not sure whether this is an option for you.

That said, I have another scenario illustrating how partial modules can be useful/necessary. Consider a case where code generation is used to create a file consisting of a single large Module. That Module contains both Public and Private methods. A developer may want/need to create new methods (outside of the generated code) that make use of the Private methods. If the generated file were to consist of a Partial Module, the developer could simply create another source file and add to that Partial Module.

I would be interested in solutions to this problem when Partial Module is not an option (i.e. pre-VS2015). Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm not sure your scenario is a good one, as if you need to use a private method outside the file you created it you might have a conception issue. However, without the module being partial, you can still declare the methods as friend, and there your conception model makes more sense.